# LavaLamp menu (jquery) links not working

Tags: jquery, lavalamp

I want to implement the LavaLamp menu style in my site. The effect works fine (so far tested in Chrome) but when I click on any element with a link it doesn't go anywhere. This is the script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#1, #2, #3").lavaLamp({
        fx: "backout", 
        speed: 700,
        click: function(event, menuItem) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I tried adding *active: "a.default",* and *header: "a.lavaLamp-label"* and the links work but the effect stops doing so. I also tried *adding $('a').attr("target")* obtaining same results. Any ideas? Here is the page where I am trying it: http://pasionesargentas.webatu.com/test4.php?id=4
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with LavaLamp, but I think you need to not return false in the click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return false will do an event.preventDefault when clicking on a link, hence removing its default behavior.